# which timezone it will take in date.timezone

Tags: php, timezone, ini

In my `php.ini` file its showing `date.timezone => no value` and `Default timezone => America/Los_Angeles`

I have added 
`date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`timezone in my script.

Which timezone it will take `date_default_timezone_set` or `php.ini` timezone?

Comment: you set date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); in your script then it will take this timezone

Comment: no its showing different timezone which is 3 hours ahead

Comment: i created test file and set date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); timezone in top of the file and i got current time of Los angeles. can you please provide me your code

Comment: @Hardik if you have set timezone at the top, put `echo date_default_timezone_get();` below that you will come to know which timezone it is taking.

Comment: it takes 'America/Los_Angeles' timezone

Comment: Here is the code

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo '<br><br>'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: Correct! that is what you have set in your script. So what you want to do now?